# Android - NPE when setText in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, custom-adapter

This has been asked many times on stack overflow and i have tried a lot of them but i am still getting Null Pointer Exception when i call setText method on TextView in my Custom Adapter. I have to display all inbox messages, where first textview shows sender's number and second textView shows the sms. Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sms> {
          private final Context context;
          private final List<Sms> msgs;
          private LayoutInflater inflater;

          public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Sms> msgs) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, msgs);
            this.context = context;
            this.msgs = msgs;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          }



          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
              Sms s = getItem(position);
              View vi = convertView;
              ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
              if (vi == null) {
                  vi = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                  vh.number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
                  vh.msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sms);
                  vi.setTag(vh);
              }
              try{
                  vh.number.setText(s.getReadState());
                  vh.msg.setText(s.getMsg());
              }
              catch (NullPointerException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              return vi;

          }


    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        TextView number;
        TextView msg;
    }
```

Please have a look at my code and tell me where am i going wrong. If any other part of code/xml is required, i ll put if you tell me. I have spent many hours on this now.

Edit: Here is the logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gitanshu.smsiknow.MainActivity$MyArrayAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:79)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
    at android.widget.ListView.correctTooLow(ListView.java:1450)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:648)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4087)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:112)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 79 here is this one:

```
vh.number.setText(s.getReadState());
```

Comment: Please post your Logcat.

Comment: @Prmths added logcat. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why an exception is thrown is because `ViewHolder.message` and `ViewHolder.msg` are never assigned a value whe `vi != null`. The root cause is that you're not applying the ViewHolder pattern correctly:

You shouldn't be creating a new `ViewHolder` instance on every iteration - that defeats the purpose of the pattern. In stead, retrieve the `ViewHolder` from the previously tagged view iff a recycled view is passed in. This `else` case is currently completely missing in your code and a try-catch will no magically make your code work correctly.

If you make the changes outlined above, you should end up with something that resembles the following. Note that I typed this directly into the browser, so be aware of any obvious typos.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Sms s = getItem(position);
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder vh;
    if (vi == null) {
        vi = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder();            
        vh.number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.number);
        vh.msg = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.sms);
        vi.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag(); 
    }

    vh.number.setText(s.getReadState());
    vh.msg.setText(s.getMsg());

    return vi;

}
```

Comment: I edited my code the same way as you mentioned but i still get the same exception and same logcat.
And try catch was just to avoid seeing that ugly error on just logcat instead of phone.

Comment: What's the content of `R.layout.list_item`? In theory the same line may still throw a NPE if `number == null`, which can happen if the view couldn't be found in the layout. Anyways, that's just a bit of a shot in the dark - please step through your code with a debugger attached and post back what exactly is `null`.

Comment: I ran my code through debugger and looks like even after i set findViewById for both textviews, they are coming to be null. ie debugger shows vh.msg =  null and vh.number = null

Comment: Ah, I see what's probably going wrong: the `findViewById()` call be happening of the layout that was just inflated. Right now, the lookup happens in your `Activity`. Change `findViewById(R.id.number)` to `vi.findViewById(R.id.number)` and do the same for `sms`. I've also updated my answer to reflect this correction.

Comment: Oh my god! I would have gone mad on this. This works. Thank you very much. :D (can't upvote due to low reputation :P but marked as accepted)

Comment: No worries, it is easy to overlook - I did it too. ;) Happy coding!